# Is it possible to add a scrollable list of buttons to the Touchbar using the Catalyst API?

Tags: swift, macos, uikit, mac-catalyst, nstouchbar

Using AppKit you can embed the buttons in a `NSScrollView`. Is there any way to do that using the  `NSTouchbar` API exposed through UIKit on Mac Catalyst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible right now as `NSCustomTouchBarItem` and `NSScrubber` are unavailable in Mac Catalyst yet.

[image]